# VS 2022 Blazor webassembly PWA template not installable

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have VS 2022. I am creating a Blazor Webassembly app from the installed template. The resulting app is not installable on chrome or Edge. I was following a tutorial step by step but cannot get past step one because my PWA is not installable. I will incluse what I can here for reference. I have made no edits to the generated code.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "APEXHealth.UI",
  "short_name": "APEXHealth.UI",
  "start_url": "./",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#03173d",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

The install button is not visible.
I did notice that chrome does not see the manifest

[Image of chrome not seing manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWigv.png)

I don't know what else to include. This is just the barebones generated template for Blazor Web assembly with PWA selected. I did not select .net hosting

Answer (score 0):

The manifest for caching is only compiled in published mode, if you look at the file *service-worker.js*, you will see its almost empty, but you should also have a *service-worker.published.js*. This is the file that will be use to cache. Once its cached, it will be available to PWA.

This is to prevent bugs because of caching when debugging. But, you can take what is in the published version and put it in the regular version, but be aware that it might and probably will cause some bugs eventually, because old files and new files will not mix well in the cache, or changes made will not be reflected and you will need to refresh cache.

Here's some useful information [Made to work only in Published](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#offline-support-only-when-published-1)